# How can I change background color of items of a ListView in Xaml?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a `ListView`, and I need to replace it's native `colors` (both of the selected item and other items) to different colors. I was not able to find how to do that. I can change the background color to something different (see my code below), but I don't know how to make it behave as a common `ListView`, changing item colors on selection.

Here is my code:

```
<ListView x:Name="MenuItemsListView"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          HasUnevenRows="true"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
  <ListView.Header>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Source="Assets\logo.png" />
    </Grid>
  </ListView.Header>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell Height="100">
         <StackLayout Padding="15,10" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LogoBackgroundColor}">
            <Image WidthRequest="50" Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
            <Label VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                Text="{Binding Title}" 
                FontSize="24"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Do you need xaml only code behind is ok?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I would prefer xaml, but I would consider code behind, in case I don't find anything for xaml. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is possible using `Triggers` as well in xaml but this is also going to work.

To change `color` of the selected `ViewCell`, there is a simple work around without using custom renderer. Make the `Tapped` event of your `ViewCell` as below

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell Tapped="ViewCell_Tapped">            
       <StackLayout></StackLayout>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In your `ContentPage`'s cs file, implement the event

```
private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(lastCell!=null)
        lastCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    var viewCell = (ViewCell)sender;
    if (viewCell.View != null)
    {
        viewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        lastCell = viewCell;
    }
}
```

Declare `lastCell` at the top of your `ContentPage` like this `ViewCell lastCell;`

Output screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Strange, but the colors don't change, even though the execution does come to the line viewCell.View.BackgroundColor = Color.Red; ...

Comment: This didn't work for me on Android (didn't try iOS). This answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67830897/1214875

Comment: I've confirmed this works on Android, on current version of XForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do something like that in XAML. You may do something like [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53595603/202179), if it is not working you may place a Grid inside ViewCell and change its color, it is the closest you can be to XAML only. But it is fairly inefficient.

The only true solution of your problem is on the native side. On Android it is fairly simple, you can edit styles.xml to achieve that. On other platforms you will need to write custom renderers.

Comment: Thank you. I am very new to Xamarin. BTW, I use UWP.