# Xamarin.Forms ListView Selected Item To Stay Highlighted Until Deselected or Other Item Selected

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

I am trying to figure out how to keep an item showing as selected (so highlighted) until another item is selected or until selected item is deselected.

Currently, I have list view of Cars whose ItemSelected is bound to a SelectedCar property in my view-model.  If I tap on an item, SelectedCar property is set to the tapped item and the item is briefly highlighted (to show it was tapped on) **but intermediately after, the highlight is gone**.  This is all default Listview behavior in Xamarin.

However, since I am not planning to initiate an action once item is Selected, but once user selects item and then taps on a button, I want to keep this item stay highlighted, until the button is tapped, or until another item is selected by the user.

Currently, my XAML is like:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstCars" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" SelectionMode="Single" 
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                ...
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

, and my view-model has the SelectedCar property bound to SelectedItem like:

```
private CarDataModel _selectedCar;
public CarDataModel SelectedCar 
{ 
    get { return _selectedCar; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedCar != value)
        {
            _selectedCar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine but I would like the item I tap to stay highlighted (so user sees it is selected) until I tap on a Button or until I tap on another item to select it.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595003/how-can-i-change-background-color-of-a-listview-in-xaml/53595603#53595603

Comment: use item tabbed event & SelectionMode="None"